# is there such thing like belongsToThrow() in laravelel elecuent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have three models **customer**, **order** and **transaction**

order **belongsTo** customer.
transaction **belongsTo** order

i want to return a **belongTo** customer relationship from transaction model but without storing customer_id in transactions table because i'm already storing order_id and in orders table i'm storing customer_id

i did like this in transaction model

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
} 

public function customer()
{
    return $this->order->customer();
}
```

when i call `Transaction::first()->customer;`
it works fine but unfortunately it doesn't work with nova i think because its taking it be ajax request, how can i fix that or is there better way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no such thing that comes with laravel out of the box, but there is a plugin **[Belongs to throw](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through)** that provides that exact functionality, exactly like other relationship methods that come with laravel